# How do I check hash data exists by hashname

Tags: redis

How do i check hash data exists by hashname?

```
> hset test record1 data1
> hset test record2 data2
> hset test record3 data3
> hgetall test

127.0.0.1:6379> hgetall test
1) "record1"
2) "data1"
3) "record2"
4) "data2"
5) "record3"
6) "data3"

127.0.0.1:6379> hexists test
(error) ERR wrong number of arguments for 'hexists' command
```

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this command, it will solve your problem.

```
redis> EXISTS test
(integer) 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [HLEN](http://redis.io/commands/HLEN), if that returns zero then they hash does not exist.

```
redis> HLEN test
(integer) 3
redis> HLEN non_existent_hash_key
(integer) 0
```

Comment: HLEN also working, But EXISTS is optimized than HLEN